# How to filter a List of objects in Android

Tags: java, android, listadapter

I am trying to create an android application (New to it)!

My question is as follows:
Suppose I am an administrator of a university X.
I need to put a list of courses each with different points.

E.g:

- Medicine: 30
- Physics: 28
- Maths: 24
- English: 20

Now suppose a student enter the point 28.

My app should be able to detect the course that has 28 points but also that of lower points. That is; Physics, Maths and English BUT NOT Medicine!!!

Can anyone help me on this? I have searched everywhere but no results yet!

Please guys am having a hard time doing this! Thank you!

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;


 public class MainActivity extends  Activity {


  String[] courses = new String[]{

        "Mathematics",
        "Chemical Engineering",
        "Civil Engineering",
        "Agriculture",
        "Law and Management",
        "Sociology",
        "Information and Communication Technologies",
        "Computer Science",
        "Information Systems",
        "Software Engineering",


};

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.event2icon);
    EditText editText = null;
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    final String point=editText.getText().toString();
    final int point_integer=Integer.parseInt(point);


    final ListView courselist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.courseNames);


    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewheader,  courselist, false);
    courselist.addHeaderView(header, null, false);


    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, courses);
    courselist.setAdapter(adapter);
    courselist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int   position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //we use the items of the listview as title of the next activity
            if((Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(point_integer))<=10))
            {


            }
        }

      });

  }
 }
```

---

**event2icon.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:text="Enter your points:"/>
     <ListView
    android:id="@+id/courseNames"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:dividerHeight="15.0sp"
        >
   </ListView>


  </LinearLayout>
```

---

**listviewheader.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you able to do this in Java? This isn't specifically an Android problem.

Comment: I see you have an `OnItemClickListener`. That will let you click on the individual courses and shouldn't have anything to do with the `EditText`.

Comment: Means i have to remove that part of OnItemClickListener. My aim is to when a person enter his point (in edittext);he automatically gets the list of courses based on his points.

Comment: If you want to filter the courses *as you type*, you'll need a [`TextWatcher`](http://javatechig.com/android/android-textwatcher-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to perform all the steps weston mentioned in his answer, otherwise, I'm afraid me just giving you the code won't teach you very much.

Instead, I will provide you the pieces mentioned in the other answer.

> You want a class that represents the course, with name and points fields

This is a simple model class. An introduction to Java course teaches these.

```
public class Course {

    private String name;
    private int points;

    public Course(String name, int points) {
        this.name = name;
        this.points = points;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

> A list that contains the instances of these courses

You just have Strings, not points listed in your code, so how did you expect to use numbers to filter the courses? Here is an example of the sample courses you listed as an array.

```
Course[] courses = new Course[]{
        new Course("Medicine", 30),
        new Course("Physics", 28),
        new Course("Math", 24),
        new Course("English", 20)
};
```

> You need an activity that includes a text box for student to enter number into

This requires you to write some XML, which you have already done in `event2icon.xml`. I suggest you add a `Button`, though because hitting Enter within the `EditText` this will insert a newline. You could also accept only numbers while you are creating this. Here is the full XML I suggest.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter your points"
                android:id="@+id/editText"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Search"
                android:id="@+id/btn_search"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/courseNames"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

> You need to parse the text to an integer

You know how to do this - the question, though is *when* do you do this? The code you posted immediately gets the text out of the `EditText` as soon as the Activity is loaded, which will be empty. You should instead extract the text from the `EditText` when you click the button. This will get you started.

```
Button searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
```

> You need to iterate over list you defined. And by using the less than or equal operator <=, you'll find the courses you need

This is just a simple for-each loop over the Courses array you have defined. Once you have found the Course object, add it to the adapter. You should also be aware that you'll need to convert the `Course[]` to a `List<Course>` in order to do this, otherwise you'll get an error.

```
List<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<Course>(Arrays.asList(courses));
// initialize the adapter with courseList instead of courses 
final ArrayAdapter<Course> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Course>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, courseList);

// this code inside the Button's onClick
int points = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
for (Course c : courses) {
    if (c.getPoints() <= points) {
        adapter.add(c);
    }
}
```

> Use a ListAdapter to display the list nicely

You already have an `ArrayAdapter`, so you are good here. One last detail, though, is that when you click the `Button`, you should first [`clear`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#clear()) the adapter before adding courses back into it. Otherwise, you'll get duplicates.

Comment: Sir actually i have been learning android programming since last 2 months and thats only by myself. Thats why am not able to understand your solution and its getting messy in project.Anyway thanks a lot for your precious time :)

Comment: It shouldn't be messy... You should only have to update two java files, `Class.java` and `MainActivity.java`; and one XML layout file `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: Still am having a hard time. I don't know where actually to place your given codes and how to continue with it. :/

Comment: Can you not see the equivalent pieces when you compare it to your original code? In MainActivity, `Course[]` replaces `String[]`. You already have an `EditText`, a `ListView`, and an `ArrayAdapter`. All I really did was remove the headerView, change the XML to add a `Button`, then setup a click listener in Java which operates on the `adapter` to do the logic of your question.

Comment: still i don't understand which codes is to be put in class.java and activity.java. anyways i will need to remove this section in my app. nevermind thanks for your explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't find anything because you need to break the problem up and research each little bit:

- You want a class that represents the course, with name and points
  fields.
- A list that contains the instances of these courses (as you listed).
- You need an activity that includes a text box for student to enter
  number into.
- You need to parse the text to an integer.
- You need to iterate over list you defined.
- And by using the less than or equal operator `<=`, you'll find the
  courses you need.
- In Android you should use a
  [`ListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html)
  to display the list nicely.

Comment: can you write the above android program for the problem i have stated above please? you exactly pinpointed the solution of my problem.Please,please!

Comment: @joey - StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Start by writing a layout file in XML with an EditText, a Button, and a ListView. Then inflate that layout in an Activity. Then assign some views and do all the logic mentioned in this post.

Comment: It won't help you learn Android to get someone else to do your work. And what would your professor say about it?

Comment: @weston:sorry sir,wont repeat that mistake of mine.Please check my above code: am not able to put points for each course and iterate over list the list displaying the list using listadapter as you said.

Comment: @cricket_007:Sir please find my above code am not able to perform all steps above.Kindly guide me.

Comment: First step was create a class for a course. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html