# How to parse an integer and it gives a list of courses in android studio?

Tags: android

am developing an android application. My problem statement is as follows:

**1)** I need to have a `ListView` of courses available at some colleges.

**2)** I the points for each of them(e.g medicine:30,maths:24,English:14,French:28,etc...)

**3)** I need to parse the points(integer) to corresponding courses and lower courses than that.

**Full sample:**

Enter your points:(say integer 26 )(edittext)
After the person added his point he gets a list of courses he is likely to apply at the college like that:
You are eligible to apply for these courses:
maths
english(to be listed in as a listview)

P.s am using android studio.
can someone help me programmatically? thanks

```
mainactivity.java


import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
 import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.ListView;


  public class MainActivity extends  Activity {


  String[] courses = new String[]{

    "Mathematics",
    "Chemical Engineering",
    "Civil Engineering",
    "Agriculture",
    "Law and Management",
    "Sociology",
    "Information and Communication Technologies",
    "Computer Science",
    "Information Systems",
    "Software Engineering",


     };




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.event2icon);
  EditText editText = null;
  editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
  final String point=editText.getText().toString();
   final int point_integer=Integer.parseInt(point);


   final ListView courselist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.courseNames);


  LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
  ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewheader,    courselist, false);
    courselist.addHeaderView(header, null, false);


    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, courses);
   courselist.setAdapter(adapter);
     courselist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int     position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //we use the items of the listview as title of the next activity
        if((Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(point_integer))<=10))
        {


        }




    }


  });

   }
   }




event2icon.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/edit_text"
android:text="Enter your points:"/>
 <ListView
android:id="@+id/courseNames"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/edit_text"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:dividerHeight="15.0sp"
    >
  </ListView>


 </LinearLayout>



 listviewheader.xml


  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
   >


 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code you have tried to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter a List of objects in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271311/how-to-filter-a-list-of-objects-in-android)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @cricket_007:here is my attached code.Please help me..am not m not able to put points for each course and iterate over list the list displaying the list using listadapter.

Comment: This code is exactly the same as the duplicate post I mentioned. I will answer there because that question was asked before yours and you can close this answer. No point in keeping both.

Comment: Please see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34318017/2308683)

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse points into integer and then by pass that integer to query to get list of eligible courses ;get point_integer from below code and use it into your query for database or arraylist and set aadapter to listview for eligible courses list related to that point

```
    String point=edittext.getText().toString.trim();
int point_integer=Integer.parseInt(point);
```

Comment: sir please help me in correcting the code.am am not m not able to put points for each course and iterate over list the list displaying the list using listadapter

Comment: by which condition you will define that if user has 26 points then he is eligible to which courses??